# How do I fix libcrypto?

Tags: python, django, macos, libpq

I made the mistake of copying the `libcrypto.*` files from `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib` to `/usr/lib` because I was getting errors from `Psycopg2` saying it needed `1.0.0` and I only had `0.9.8` or something along those lines and now, I'm stuck with the following and I can't find a solution (well, this was a solution to my problem, but a bad one). How can I fix this?

```
taylor-pc:python taylor$ mkvirtualenv testingenv
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
New python executable in testingenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools..............................................................
  Complete output from command /Users/taylor/Projec...estingenv/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])






" /Library/Python/2.7/...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg:
  ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 103, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 67, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/md5.py", line 10, in <module>
    from hashlib import md5
ImportError: cannot import name md5
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.7.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 942, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1052, in create_environment
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 598, in install_setuptools
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 570, in _install_req
    cwd=cwd)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1020, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/taylor/Projec...estingenv/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])






" /Library/Python/2.7/...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Check which package installed libcrypto*, then remove these first and re-install that package.

Comment: Don't you have access to any computer with the same OS X version installed ? I guess they were installed at the same than the OS so you can restore them by simply copying from another machine.

Comment: @Rohan the libcrypto.* files are from my PostgreSQL install, I copied them over.

Comment: @niconoe Haha, no, I wish. :p